# Rock Paper Scissors return issue

Tags: python

So the problem I'm having is my counter keeps reseting when it try to add up the figures
I tried figuring out a way to make the counter portion into a function but I couldnt figure it out

```
winP1=0
winP2=0
tie=0

ans = input('Would you like to play ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS?: ')

while ans == 'y':
    p1c = input('Player 1 enter either R,P, or S: ') #p1c stands for "player 1 choice"
    p2c = input('Player 2 enter either R,P, or S: ')
    ans = input('Would you like to play again: ')

def game(p1c,p2c):
    if p1c == p2c:                  #if its a tie we are going to add to the Tie variable
        return 0
    elif p1c == 'R' and p2c == 'P': #We will only set the Player 1 wins because
        return 1                    #player 2 wins can be set as else
    elif p1c == 'P' and p2c == 'S':
        return 1
    elif p1c == 'S' and p2c == 'R':
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

result = game(p1c,p2c)   
if result == -1:
    winP2 += 1
if result == 0:
    tie += 1
else:
    winP1 +=1

print('Player 1 won {} times. \nPlayer 2 won {} times. \nThere were {} ties.'.format(winP1,winP2,tie))
```

Comment: Seems that in your program, the while loop will go on forever.

Comment: @alKid No, it won't: 'ans' changes in the last line of the while loop based on user input.

Comment: @ChristianTernus
I tried working with is but now I'm running into the issue of
 local variable 'tie' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow and to Python programming! I hope you have a great time here.

Your counter keeps resetting because, to the system, you're only playing one game:

```
while ans == 'y':
    p1c = input('Player 1 enter either R,P, or S: ') #p1c stands for "player 1 choice"
    p2c = input('Player 2 enter either R,P, or S: ')
    ans = input('Would you like to play again: ')
```

I'm going to move some things around in your code to get you the result you want, editing minimally, and hopefully that'll show you what you need to do. You're on the right track!

We'll use a dictionary called `state` to keep track of the game state and pass it around.

```
state = {
   'winP1':0,  
   'winP2':0,
   'tie':0
}

def game(p1c,p2c):
    if p1c == p2c:                  #if its a tie we are going to add to the Tie variable
        return 0
    elif p1c == 'R' and p2c == 'P': #We will only set the Player 1 wins because
        return 1                    #player 2 wins can be set as else
    elif p1c == 'P' and p2c == 'S':
        return 1
    elif p1c == 'S' and p2c == 'R':
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def process_game(p1c, p2c, state): # Move this into a function
    result = game(p1c,p2c)   
    if result == -1:
        state['winP2'] += 1
    if result == 0:
        state['tie'] += 1
    else:
        state['winP1'] +=1

while ans == 'y':
    p1c = input('Player 1 enter either R,P, or S: ') #p1c stands for "player 1 choice"
    p2c = input('Player 2 enter either R,P, or S: ')
    process_game(p1c, p2c, state)
    ans = input('Would you like to play again: ')

print('Player 1 won {} times. \nPlayer 2 won {} times. \nThere were {} ties.'.format(state['winP1'],state['winP2'],state['tie']))
```

Comment: I tried working with is but now I'm running into the issue of
 local variable 'tie' referenced before assignment

Comment: Right! I've put in a `global` declaration, which isn't usually a good idea but gets the job done. Really, what you want to do is move the game state into its own object and pass that object around.

Comment: I hate to ask but I haven't gone over the global idea and id rather not use it. Could you show me the game state passing through?

Comment: Yeah I remember seeing something like that before!
I got it working now
thanks so much
you are king